# OpenCV color_bgr2gray error

Tags: python, opencv

There are a bunch of questions about this function throwing errors, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822288/python-opencv-cv2-opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4-in-unkno) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052042/opencv-error-assertion-failed-when-using-color-bgr2gray-function) but I think mine has a unique twist. What I'm trying to do is go through all the images in a folder and detect any faces.

```
import cv2
import sys
import os

#Get the folder to be searched and the location of the cascade file from arguments
imageDirectory = sys.argv[1]
cascadePath = sys.argv[2]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)

#Iterate over the png files in the directory
for imagePath in os.listdir(imageDirectory):
    if imagePath.endswith(".png"):
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30, 30)
            #flags = cv2.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
        )
```

The first image will be processed correctly, but then the second will throw an error:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/opencv3-20170202-24427-1s95vpr/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9748
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_detect_flip.py", line 22, in 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv3-20170202-24427-1s95vpr/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

The files are all color .pngs so I can't tell why the script will work on some of them but not others. Sometimes changing the order or the filename (but not the extension) will change whether the script runs or not, but not in any pattern that I can discern.

Comment: Unsuprisingly `cv2.imread` can fail to load an image. It tends to be a good practice to test for that and handle such situation appropriately. You fail to do so.

Comment: But why would changing the filename or the order in which files are loaded lead to failure? Sure I can test for it, but I still want to load it at some point.

Comment: That's rather difficult to tell without having the relevant context, which in this case would be the parameters you give the program and the contents of the directory you tell it to process. Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "changing the order or the filename"? Perhaps provide some examples of what works and what doesn't? | Obviously you want to load it as some point. One of the reasons for the test is to clearly identify problems when they occur -- it's much more meaningful to see something like "Failed to load file 'foo.png'" than the error you show.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the image that causes this error does not have 3 (rgb image) or 4 (rgba image) channels. The *cvtColor* function needs the the image to have at least 3 channels to convert it.

One possible reason could be that the file isn't being read correctly. This would cause the variable image to be None and hence it wont have the correct number of channels.

Another reason could be if the image has fewer channels. Maybe it's a grayscale image to begin with and thus has only one channel.

You can use *print(image.shape)* to check the number of channels. If the value is None then the file wasn't read correctly.